# How to add lines of a text file into individual items on a ListBox (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How would it be possible to read a text file with several lines, and then to put each line in the text file on a separate row in a ListBox?

The code I have so far:

```
richTextBox5.Text = File.ReadAllText("ignore.txt");
```

Comment: If you are using .Net 4.0 consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: it is a one-liner:             listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("ignore.txt"));

Comment: @Hans Passant Why don't you post the answer? I believe it is the best

Comment: It is only shorter, not better.  You can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String text = File.ReadAllText("ignore.txt");

var result = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n");

foreach(string s in result)
{
  lstBox.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I get an error: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'RealAllText'

Comment: it's problematic if file is big, also Regex is an overkill

Comment: @lukas: If the file is big, it wouldn't be added to a ListBox.

Comment: typo - I was just using what you provided in your original example.  There are many many ways to read the textfile and split it into lines, this is just one possible approach.  Jalal has another approach in his response

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"ignore.txt");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: A good answer. I am lazy and would just write this: listBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"ignore.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

You should use a streamreader to read the file one line at a time.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("ignore.txt"))
{
  string line;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

StreamReader info -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

ListBox info -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx

Comment: Why? You end up with the all the lines as strings anyway, this just makes the code more complicated.

Comment: you do not relase the resources

Comment: @lukas - the using block will dispose of the StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper method that return the collection of lines

```
   static IEnumerable<string> ReadFromFile(string file) 
    {// check if file exist, null or empty string
        string line;
        using(var reader = File.OpenText(file)) 
        {
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
```

use it

```
var lines = ReadFromFile(myfile);
myListBox.ItemsSource = lines.ToList(); // or change it to ObservableCollection. also you can add to the end line by line with myListBox.Items.Add()
```

Comment: Why not use `File.ReadAllLines()` or `File.ReadLines()`?

Comment: It can be used with LINQ where ReadAllLines not. Also ReadAllLines return array which I hate cause of its immutable size (ye sometimes is helpful).

Comment: Oh doc of File.ReadLines was Updated: June 2010. Seems better way to read a file.

Comment: Regex is harder to understand and adds not necessary noise. If I wanted to use it, isted of "\r\n|\r|\n" I would use  Environment.NewLine to be system independent (Nowadays there's not only Unix and Windows - a lot of exotic device)

Comment: `T[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so it *can* be used with LINQ. Some LINQ operations are even optimized for it (and other collections that implement `IList<T>`.

Comment: What does the time the doc was last updated to do with anything? And I'm not saying you should use a regex.

Comment: Sure it can, but array can mutates where IEnumberable cannot.

Comment: File.ReadLines is only .Net 4.0